# How can I update my build files for a Jetpack Compose desktop application to fix a NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, desktop-application, jetpack-compose-navigation

I try to do a mini project (stopWatch) this is the source code of this project https://github.com/philipplackner/StopWatchComposeDesktop , that I saw on the web. I don't have any compilation problems, but I have a runtime issue. I compared my source files with his source files, and they are equal. But the build files are diferent this is my project https://github.com/victorYghor/StopWatch3. The problem is when I try to click in one button i get the following problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUF3K.png)

```
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelled}@19d52b0, Dispatchers.Main[missing, cause=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Looper]]
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.ui.awt.ComposeLayer$coroutineExceptionHandler$1@786a520b, androidx.compose.runtime.BroadcastFrameClock@46a56726, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@36a64531, FlushCoroutineDispatcher@657df46]
```

This is the build.gradle.kts that work

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.31"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.0"
}

group = "me.philipplackner"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "StopWatchComposeDesktop"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Below you can see my build.gradle.kts that don't work

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    id("org.jetbrains.compose")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        jvmToolchain(11)
        withJava()
    }
    sourceSets {
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-javafx")
                implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
                implementation ("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:0.30.1")
            }
        }
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "StopWatch"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know, how is possible update my build files for I don't have more runtime problems.

I belived that I need to change some parametrs in gradle build file.
Another thing that may help is that the problem start in line 22 of StopWatch.kt

````
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.*

class StopWatch {
    var formattedTime by mutableStateOf("00:00:000")

    private var coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    private var isActive = false
    private var timeMillis = 0L
    private var lastTimestamp = 0L

    fun start() {
        if (isActive) return

        coroutineScope.launch { \\ THE PROBLEM START HERE
            lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            this@StopWatch.isActive = true
            while(this@StopWatch.isActive) {
                delay(10L)
                timeMillis += System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimestamp
                lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                formattedTime = formatTime(timeMillis)
            }
        }
    }

    fun pause() {
        isActive = false
    }

    fun reset() {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
        coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
        timeMillis = 0L
        formattedTime = "00:00:000"
        isActive = false
    }
    private fun formatTime(timeMillis: Long): String {
        val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeMillis),
            ZoneId.systemDefault()
        )
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "mm:ss:SSS",
            Locale.getDefault()
        )
        return localDateTime.format(formatter)
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

what solve the problem to me was not use Dispatchers.Main, for some reason the erro was arrive from this. If I create a dedicate thread for my coroutines everything works fine I use `Dispatchers.Default`

````
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.time.Instant
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneId
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.util.*


class StopWatch {
    var formattedTime by mutableStateOf("00:00:000")
    val threadSW = Dispatchers.Default
    private var coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(threadSW)
    private var isActive = false
    private var timeMillis = 0L
    private var lastTimestamp = 0L

    fun start() {
        if (isActive) return

        coroutineScope.launch {
            lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            this@StopWatch.isActive = true
            while(this@StopWatch.isActive) {
                delay(10L)
                timeMillis += System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimestamp
                lastTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                formattedTime = formatTime(timeMillis)
            }
        }
    }

    fun pause() {
        isActive = false
    }

    fun reset() {
        coroutineScope.cancel()
        coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(threadSW)
        timeMillis = 0L
        formattedTime = "00:00:000"
        isActive = false
    }
    private fun formatTime(timeMillis: Long): String {
        val localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
            Instant.ofEpochMilli(timeMillis),
            ZoneId.systemDefault()
        )
        val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
            "mm:ss:SSS",
            Locale.getDefault()
        )
        return localDateTime.format(formatter)
    }
}```
this is the changes how I make
````